# how to set my config file in viper present outside of my working repository

Tags: go, path

I need to set a path to my config file. The problem is, for example, my config file is in `my_app/config` but my working directory is in `my_app/workingdir` and I should not set an absolute path or a path from my working dir because in production the absolute path and working directory will change. For test I know I can set the path from my code location, but I need a cleaner way.

```
    workingdir, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error(err)
    }
    viper.SetConfigFile(workingdir + "/config/local.yaml")
```

Comment: `$HOME` should always be there and point to a directory, where by convention you can either create a dotfile or dotdirectory for your config. Problem solved.

Comment: this actually helped @MarkusWMahlberg

Answer (score 2):

Don't keep your config file out of your working directory, always make a new folder in your main package like conf and put your file into it.

So, the directory structure will be

> my_app/conf/config.yml

Then set the config file into viper through init function of your main.go

```
//main.go
func init() {
  setUpViper()
}

func setUpViper() {
  viper.AddConfigPath("./conf")
  viper.SetConfigName("config")
}
```

Comment: this actually works but this is a big project and setting viper in main.go is not gonna work

Comment: @SepehrNoori this has nothing to do with main.go

Comment: @TheFool yeah correct (Y), the above solution can be implemented in any file and through any function. But, generally we setup our viper at the start before everything goes on. It's a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `..` to go to parent directory, and then from there go to `config` folder.

```golang
workingdir, err := os.Getwd()
if err != nil {
    logger.Error(err)
}
viper.SetConfigFile(workingdir + "/../config/local.yaml")
```

Comment: this will go down in the production when the working directory changes

Answer (score 1):

Use ".." to specify  a parent of a directory.

Because relative paths are rooted at the working directory, there's no need to get the working directory in the application code.

Use the following to specify the path to the configuration file:

```
 viper.SetConfigFile("../config/local.yaml")
```